# Selenium tests execution in headless chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-headless

I am currently running Selenium tests on headless chrome browser. Below are 
my chrome settings:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

When I try to read a web element it says No such element found exception.
I tried adding the below wait as well:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 150);
    WebElement usernameTextfield = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("j_username")));
```

This time it say a different error :

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.name: j_username (tried for 150 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
at com.bcs.p3s.automationtest.TestP3sLogin.loginCorrectCredentials(TestP3sLogin.java:135)
at com.bcs.p3s.automationtest.TestP3sLogin.main(TestP3sLogin.java:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.name: j_username
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:03:16.397Z'
System info: host: 'AVID-OX790-013', ip: '192.168.200.89', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.lambda$findElement$0(ExpectedConditions.java:896)
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:202)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
... 27 more
```

The issue exists only in headless chrome. When I ran the tests on actual chrome browser it works.
Can someone please help me in solving the issue?

Comment: share the relevant HTML

Comment: `<form id="ppLoginForm">
                                 <input type="text" name="j_username" class="form-control font-body pill-radius input-p-sm" placeholder="Username" data-parsley-validate-email="" data-parsley-required-message="Please ensure all fields have been completed." data-parsley-required="true">
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           .........
                        </form>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @cruise. I was trying to add the code snippet. But `BrowserVersion.CHROME` does not support. It suggests to change to FIREFOX or IE

Comment: import this one :    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;

Comment: Which IDE you are using ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I am using Eclipse. I have imported 'import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;'as well.

Comment: after writing the BrowserVersion. (Press ctrl+space to see the option ) and select chrome

Comment: The suggestions says FIREFOX or IE. But no CHROME

Comment: import this one also :  import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

Comment: In my machine it is working fine. I'm using selenium 3.11.0 with Java 1.8 and IDE is eclipse

Comment: Check this link :  http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/BrowserVersion.html

Comment: I have imported  `import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver`. I am having a maven project and my pom xml is having selenium dependency as  `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
         <version>2.29.0</version> 
     </dependency>`

Comment: You can check the provided link, in Field Summary you can check about chrome and other browsers. What's your selenium version ?

Comment: My selenium version is 3.10. The issue was because of htmlunit version. I changed to version 2.30. Now the code compiles. Thanks @cruisepandey

Comment: If your issue has resolved, then you can accept and (upvote) the answer by clicking on check sign just under the downvote button

Comment: @cruisepandey Now the code compiles. But when I run the test it throws an exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/css/parser/CSSException`

Comment: it's most likely because of maven dependency, make sure you've defined dependency correctly !

Comment: Thanks. Tests working fine now.

Comment: Glad ! That it worked for you !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code for chrome headless instance :

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME ,true);
driver.get("your web URL");  
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("ppLoginForm"))));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("j_username")));
```

try out this code !

Comment: The [official docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) state, `WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits.`.

Comment: @JeffC : is that the reason for(  -1 ) .? Yes I was aware of that, that could lead to uncertain wait time.  But it won't throw any error . What is wrong in that ? You should see the solution instead of just down voting.

Comment: Why would you recommend a practice that is expressly identified in the official docs as a bad practice? Just because something doesn't throw an error doesn't mean it's OK. Find a better solution.

Comment: @JeffC :The solution given was for headless browser, it has nothing to do with waits.

Comment: Where they have mentioned it's a bad practice ????  show me the proof ?

Comment: You added an implicit wait that was not in OP's code. It's part of your solution. If it's not relevant than remove it. You also added other waits that didn't exist so I'm not sure how this answer has nothing to do with waits... all you've changed is the waits.

Comment: Now you are just being argumentative... you generally find `WARNING` in all caps to indicate something that is recommended or otherwise OK? Go watch many of the Selenium contributor's talks at seleniumconf. They repeatedly state that it should be avoided, it's a bad practice, etc.

Comment: Look who is talking about being argumentative? You also added other waits that didn't exist  ? which wait you are talking about MR Selenium Jeffc

Comment: Scroll up and look. OP only posted 2 lines of code. You have two waits (ignoring the implicit wait) and OP only had one... so you added a wait.

Comment: @JeffC : first wait is for visibility of form that contains username field and second wait is for element to be clickable  for username field .

Answer (score -1):

What I would do instead, is to use a dirty hack (this code is in C# but is very similar to Java):

```
while (2 == 2) 
{
  try
 { 
     Thread.sleep(50);
     var element = driver.findElements(By.ClassName("username")); 
     if(element.Count > 0)  //you can change it to .size() for Java
     {
       //do the code here
       break;
     }
 }
  catch(Exception)
 {
 }

}
```